# Fulton Multiple points

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Prove that $$ P=(0,0) $$ is the only multiple point in the curve $$ (X^2+Y^2)^2 + 3X^2Y-Y^3 $$.

My effort: $$ E_Y= 4Y(X^2+Y^2)+3X^2-3Y^2 \\
E_X=4X(X^2+Y^2)+6XY $$.

Solving $$ E_Y = E_X = 0 $$ we get $$ -\frac{3}{2}Y - 4Y^2=0 $$ so we have $$ Y=0  $$ and $$ Y = -\frac{3}{8} $$ so $$ (0,0) $$ is not the only multiple point.

Where have I gone wrong?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This means that all possible multiple points on the curve have the form
$(x,0)$ or $(x,-3/8)$, In each case you should also solve for $x$ to ensure that $(0,0)$ really is the only solution.

Comment: Solving for $$ x $$, I get $$ x= \frac{\sqrt{27}}{8} $$.

Comment: Should be a plus or minus there

Comment: Got it! I have made an error in calculation. Thank you!